# Can we get a stat to show how many flags have aged away?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, flag-history

I think it'd be nice to have the flagging history section list how many of your flags have aged away, instead of the current *"older flags were not recorded helpful/declined"* text.

Sure you can calculate this number yourself, but who wants to do that? It seems like it'd be pretty easy to include on the history page, and there doesn't seem like any good reason *not* to show it. The current text is not very helpful nor informative.

**Current flagging history view:**

[image: old flagging history]

**Suggested new view:**

[image: new flagging history]

Note that the position of this stat is unimportant to me and I'm open to letting the community or SO development team decide where to place it.

Below disputed might actually be a better location than where I have placed it and this would give an intuitive flow of bad->not good->inconsequential for declined->disputed->aged away.

Comment: +1 If you can calculate this by hand, it should be pretty easy to add.

Comment: Flag history is something that needs obviously needs some work and it's on my list to start to look at...6-8 soons.  I'll add this to list of things to look at.

Comment: That's what OP was saying

Comment: @pnuts you have a total flag number, and numbers for every category other than aged away. It's simply a "subtract what you know" from the total, and then what you have left are the flags that have aged away. Even if this were not the case, you can count them up by hand (which I assume is how the system does it for the other categories).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This has been implemented in the latest build. There will now be a category to include the total number of Aged Away flags. It will look similar to this:

> [image]

Comment: The unhelpful text "* older flags were not recorded helpful/declined" is still visible on the flag page.  It's now irrelevant (as part of the feature request).  Here's a [screenshot](http://imgur.com/jFnz1LD)

Comment: @ryanyuyu Thanks for reporting, I'll see about getting that removed.